# How can I create an Interface for my DbContext if I use EfCore.BulkExtensions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mocking, entity-framework-core

I am working on an ASP.Net Core 2.0 API that uses Entity Framework Core 2.0. I am trying to build up unit tests using XUnit and Moq but I am running into an issue with creating an interface for my `DbContext` so I can mock it in my unit tests.

Currently, my project is not using an interface for my context. I am injecting it into my repository classes as its implementation. And in my `Startup.cs` I am using `services.AddDbContext` to set it up.

Example of a typical repository class constructor.

```
    public CompaniesRepository(MyDbContext myDbContext)
    {
        _myDbContext = myDbContext;
    }
```

Example of Startup.cs

```
        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbConnectionString"),
            sqlOptions =>
            {
                sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(5,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),sqlTransientErrors);
            });
        });
```

And this method has been working like this just fine.

However, now I am trying to set up unit tests and I want to be able to Mock my context so I need to create an Interface for it.

So, I added an interface to `MyDbContext` called `IMyDbContext` and added the following code to my `Startup.cs`, following recommendations in this [blog post by Jerrie Pelser](https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/resolve-dbcontext-as-interface-in-aspnet5-ioc-container/)

```
        services.AddScoped<IMyDbContext>(provider => provider.GetService<MyDbContext>());
```

Which seemed to work, except for one issue. I am also using Boris Djurdjevic's `EFCore.BulkExtensions` NuGet and so, I am getting a compile error coming from my repository classes, that now inject the `IMyDbContext` interface in their constructors, stating that my interface does not contain a definition for `BulkInsert`:

> Error CS1929 'IMyDbContext' does not contain a definition for 'BulkInsert' and the best extension method overload 'DbContextBulkExtensions.BulkInsert(DbContext, IList, BulkConfig, Action)' requires a receiver of type 'DbContext'

I assume that I need to add the `BulkInsert` extension method to my `IMyDyBontext` interface somehow but I am not sure how to do that correctly. If I just try adding the method to my interface, then I get an error saying it is not implemented in my `MyDbContext` class, of course.

How do I reference the `BulkInsert` extension method in my `MyDbContext` class?

Comment: Two things: you shouldn't test nor mock DbContext, use the InMemoryDatabase instead. Second: Repository pattern and Entity Framework Core is more an anti-pattern than anything. You are just overcomplicating everything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BulkInsert` is an extension method. You cannot mock static method *easily*.

Instead, you could implement it inside `MyDbContext` class. Then, you could mock `IMyDbContext` for unit testing. *Note: I did not test it.*

```
public interface IMyDbContext
{
    void BulkInsert<T>(IList<T> entities, BulkConfig bulkConfig = null,
        Action<decimal> progress = null) where T : class;

}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext, IMyDbContext
{
    public void BulkInsert<T>(IList<T> entities, BulkConfig bulkConfig = null,
        Action<decimal> progress = null) where T : class
    {
        this.BulkInsertOrUpdate(entities, bulkConfig, progress);
    }
}
```

Comment: This allowed the code to compile but it dumped hard when the BulkInsert methods was actually called. I need the BulkInsert as it is giving me significant performance gains so I may need to rethink the xUnit/Moq process. As Camilo Terevinto mentiond, I can try to new up an InMemory context instance to plug into my repo classes for unit testing.   I will give you the Answer since it did answer my question of how to create an interface for my DbContext

Answer (score 2):

I recently encountered this issue while preparing to mock my DbContext for unit testing when using the EF Core BulkExtensions package. The response marked as the correct answer is ***ALMOST*** correct (although they did say that they had not tested their code).

When implementing this inside the DbContext class in the way described above you will receive a StackOverflowException when calling the BulkInsert method.

So, I started debugging and decided to put a breakpoint on the method inside the DbContext class to see what was going on. This led me to understand the reason for the StackOverflowException: This method was calling itself instead of the method on the base DbContext class due to the scope of the "this" keyword.

The solution was fairly straightforward, solved by the following change to the BulkInsert method implementation inside the MyDbContext implementation:

```
public async Task BulkInsertAsync<T>(IList<T> entities, BulkConfig bulkConfig = null, Action<decimal> progress = null) where T : class
{
    await ((DbContext)this).BulkInsertAsync<T>(entities, bulkConfig, progress);
}
```

Also, add the following line to your IMyDbContext interface:

```
Task BulkInsertAsync<T>(IList<T> entities, BulkConfig bulkConfig = null, Action<decimal> progress = null) where T : class;
```

This ensured that the scope of "this" was cast to the base DbContext class type instead of the type of my own DbContext implementation. Therefore, instead of calling itself, it called the extension method using the base DbContext class.

Using this solution, you should now be able to successfully use the extension method in your code as shown below:

```
await _context.BulkInsertAsync<User>(users);
```

Hopefully someone finds this useful. It wasn't too bad to figure out through debugging and ensured I could keep all of my methods easily unit-testable when using the BulkExtensions package!